# Как вывести массив строк в textView?

Tags: java, android, android-textview

Хочу массив строк вывести списком в textView, но там отображается только последний элемент:

```
String s[]={"aa","bb","cc"};
for (int c=0;c<s.length-1;c++)
textView.setText(s[c]+"\n");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `setText()`устанавливает новое значение в виджет, уничтожая предыдущее. Для объединения с ранее существующим в виджете текстом используется метод [`append()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
String s[]={"aa","bb","cc"};
for (int c=0;c<s.length-1;c++)
textView.append(s[c]+"\n");
```

Comment: это самое короткое решение вопроса - не нужно париться с StringBuilder

Answer (score 2):

Метод setText затирает предыдущий текст. Это стоит учитывать.
Суть примерно такая:

```
String s[]={"aa","bb","cc"};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
     builder.append(s[i]);
     builder.append("\n");
}
textView.setText(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String s[]={"aa","bb","cc"};
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
    textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + s[i] + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего просто упадёт по NPE, т.к. изначально `textView.getText()` должен вернуть `null`. Даже, если вернёт пустую строку, то это неоптимально в виду существования `TextView.appendText(String text)`